# Is it possible to insert text with Subscripts/Superscripts in draw.io?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

I'm able to insert some nodes. However, within these nodes, I can't insert text that would include subscripts (for example, the expression "P_i(n)").

Answer (score 3):

Select the node, ensure it's label has HTML turned on (Text->Formatted Text):

[image: Location of the HTML label switch]

Then start editing the label (which is now HTML). The toolbar will change to the HTML label toolbar, providing a subscript option:

[image: The subscript menu option]